# C# async socket file transfer

Tags: c#, sockets

Well I'm trying to write a C# server application which will receive files from several clients written in C++ and the main problem is I'm pretty new to C# .Net.

Got managed to write one code for sync socket C# server but couldn't figure out how to receve data for an async socket byte wise and write those to a single file inside OnDataReceive callback.

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
  try
  {
    SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

    ////Original code inside this function
    //int iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
    //char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
    //System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
    //int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
    //System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
    //richTextBoxReceivedMsg.AppendText(szData);

    ////My old code from Sync socket file transfer
    //Receive data from client socket till it continues
    byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024];
    int recvBytesLen = 0;
    BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(m_strCurrFolder + "File", FileMode.Append));
    do
    {
      recvBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(bufferData, bufferData.Length, 0);
      bWrite.Write(bufferData, 0, recvBytesLen);
    } while (recvBytesLen > 0);

    //Closing file and socket once done
    bWrite.Close();

    // Continue the waiting for data on the Socket
    WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket);
  }
  catch (ObjectDisposedException)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
  }
  catch (SocketException se)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: You are already reading your data to a buffer with `recvBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(bufferData, bufferData.Length, 0);` [Socket.Receive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Is it a right way to loop through data inside a async socket server ?

Comment: Well I manage to get some code from msdn. 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Fixed-size-large-file-dfc3f45d

Answer (score 1):

Found this link to be helpful and does my job. 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Fixed-size-large-file-dfc3f45d

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
 { 
     StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState; 
     Socket clientSocket = state.WorkSocket; 
     BinaryWriter writer; 


     int bytesRead = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar); 
     if (bytesRead > 0) 
     { 
         //If the file doesn't exist, create a file with the filename got from server. If the file exists, append to the file. 
         if (!File.Exists(fileSavePath)) 
         { 
             writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileSavePath, FileMode.Create)); 
         } 
         else 
         { 
             writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileSavePath, FileMode.Append)); 
         } 


         writer.Write(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
         writer.Flush(); 
         writer.Close(); 


         // Notify the progressBar to change the position. 
         Client.BeginInvoke(new ProgressChangeHandler(Client.ProgressChanged)); 


         // Recursively receive the rest file. 
         try 
         { 
             clientSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state); 
         } 
         catch 
         { 
             if (!clientSocket.Connected) 
             { 
                 MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.DisconnectMsg); 
             } 
         } 
     } 
     else 
     { 
         // Signal if all the file received. 
         receiveDone.Set(); 
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Well thanks for pointing me out that. Now while connecting multiple clients at the same time, I think there should be a seperate thread for this callback, but I'm not sure as the callback actually runs its own thread at low level. 

Anyone?